# Onclick to show content and target="_blank" another link

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, show-hide

I need a button onclick to show content ,at the same time it will target="_blank" a new window too ...is it possible to that ? 
I had tried some code but not works ,can anyone help me to fix that ?
thanks guys !

```
<style type="text/css">
   /* This CSS is used for the Show/Hide functionality. */
   .more {
      display: none;
      border-top: 1px solid #666;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #666; }
   a.showLink, a.hideLink {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #36f;
      padding-left: 8px;
      background: transparent url(down.gif) no-repeat left; }
   a.hideLink {
      background: transparent url(up.gif) no-repeat left; }
   a.showLink:hover, a.hideLink:hover {
      border-bottom: 1px dotted #36f; }
</style>

<div id="wrap">
<h1>Show/Hide Content</h1>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?app_id=309437425817038&sdk=joey&u=http%3A%2F%2Fcloudsblack.com%2F180115f.html&display=popup&ref=plugin"
id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">
<button class="btn-u btn-u-lg btn-block btn-u-dark-blue">
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook
</button>
</a>
<div id="example" class="more">
<p>Congratulations! You've found the magic hidden text! Clicking the link below will hide this content again.</p>
<p><a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Hide this content.</a></p>
</div>
</div>                  

<!-- Hide Function -->           
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function showHide(shID) {
   if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
      if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
      }
      else {
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why dont you handle the opening of the new window in your function? By returning false on your onclick function, you are stopping normal propagation on that event.

Comment: sorry I'm just new in Javascript ,can you teach me how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why the **return false;** behind **showHide**` .

the order of execution is:

showHide will be call first,  after , **return false;** is called , it  return false ,so the processing for href will stop .
 when the onclick event is over and not return false ,this page will jump or open new page for the targer.

Ps: your onclick event here is not **showHide('example');** is:

```
 {
    showHide('example');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hey JsonSong ! thanks for your help ! It works when I just removed return false; ! thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `target="_blank"` to your `a` tag like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?app_id=309437425817038&sdk=joey&u=http%3A%2F%2Fcloudsblack.com%2F180115f.html&display=popup&ref=plugin"
    id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">
```

Comment: Thanks Joel . I tried but no working